# How to manage a singlepage Chrome App with multiple views (or sections)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-chrome-app, singlepage

I´m starting to develop a Chrome App just to test it. 
It seems that this kind of applications (desktop app at the end) must be developped with the single-page concept in mind.

But my application consists of three pages or "sections": One to control a web-cam, another to  watch a streaming and the last to control a videoconference.

I´ve been reading and coding a bit within the Chrome Platform developing center, and just could find basic tutorials with one .html page.

So, my question is: What is the best way to load different .html pages (because i need to show different UI sections) in a Chrome App? I´ve seen that Google uses AngularJS to implement an MVC pattern, but i don´t know how to change from one view to another (thinking of views as .html pages) in that scenario (because i´ve never used AngularJS).

Thanks!

Comment: You need to looking into Angular's application routing, `ngRoute` -> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute or AngularUI's `ui-router` -> https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: @m.e.conroy If you're willing to augment it with an example code snippet, it should be an answer and not a comment.

Comment: @Xan I didn't have the time to do so a half hour ago and don't right now, but when I do I'll revisit and re-post with an example.  I just thought for someone that hasn't used Angular before that I'd point them in a direction where they may find the solution they were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason you need multiple HTML pages? It's pretty straightforward to do something like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="tab_1">Section One</div>
    <div id="tab_2">Section Two</div>
    <div id="tab_3">Section Three</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and then show/hide each div according to which part of your app you want to show. CSS frameworks like Bootstrap are designed to work well this this kind of approach, turning the set of divs into a pane with a left nav, or a content area with a tab strip, all of which match the needs of a typical app UI.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation as the OP right now. My reasons for wanting AngularJS views and routing are better managing my code (each one of the tabs in your example can have a lot of content) and that it would be nice to have it working pretty much the same way in a regular browser...